# How can I send data to a new activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

I need to start a new activity, after the user clicks on a list item.  The new activity needs to know what the user wants.  It needs to get two pieces of data. First is a class object and the other is a `String[][]`.  Can I somehow insert this data in the Intent or the Content? If so how or what other method may I use?

OK there is the bundle extras, but I still can't put what I want in there without a lot of extra processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I think the best answer is a Singleton. A web search will give you the particulars about it.  it basically is a class with a single instance. Once you put that data in it, you can access it with
    Class Lib = Class.getInstance();
The methods of the class can give you the data.
Cliff